# Process builder not firing when referencing percent field

Tags: process-builder, formula-field, field-update

I am having trouble updating a checkbox field through process builder.

There is a percent formula field on an object that calculates percentage complete. I am trying to update a separate field on the same object when the percentage is above 80.

Fields on Object -

1. Percentage complete: Formula (Percent)
2. Survey Email Sent: Checkbox

Process builder -

1. Fires on create/edit
2. Formula evaluates to be true: [object__c].Percentage_Complete__c > 80
3. Immediate Action: update Survey Email Sent field - TRUE

I know that there are other ways to trigger the update (another workflow rule/field update outside of process builder) but ideally would like to get to the bottom of how to use percentages...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formula field is getting calculated on the fly after commiting data in database.
So, criteria based on formula field will not work. Though you have not specified formula field directly here by ultimately percentage complete is calculated based on formula field.